# How To Use Appscript doPost to create a REST API?

Tags: google-apps-script

After 1 month, I would like to open the question regarding this topic once again:
Here is the whole post with all links: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tb0-twzHl-wXbvaNF2IpCT0CiONT9PoqPlEweLz3oYI/edit

There is a function in a project in which a urlFetchApp sends payload, using doPost in the second script function.
The second function stores the payload in the 1. spreadsheet: When running the first function, the second function does not store the payload in the spreadsheet. Detailed description below:

**1. project with script**

```
function merry2script() {
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzM97wKyc0en6UrqXnVZuR9KLCf-UZAEpzfzZogbYApD9KChnnM/exec';
  var payload = {payloadToSend : 'string to send'};
  var method = 'post'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method : method, payload: payload}).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
  return;
}
```

img merry2.jpg

**2. project with script**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Apjz67q9b5PldFJUYkkzVGRHdGFYc1pFYWk5T0Eyc0E");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("testsheet");
  var record;
  for (var i in e.parameters) {
    record = 'parameter: ' + i + ' = ' + e.parameters[i];
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValue(record);
  }
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  output.setContent("content to return");
  return output;
}
```

img merry_christmas.jpg

published 2.  script ,

img evidence of publishing 2.  script :
mch1.jpg

**1. spreadsheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Apjz67q9b5PldFJUYkkzVGRHdGFYc1pFYWk5T0Eyc0E

**Results:**
When the payload is sent through hurl.it(a webpage), it is not shown in the spreadsheet.
trying without result

**trying with this option**
install this chrome extension
 "Advanced REST Client"
client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
img result

**result in spreadsheet**
ss_test.jpg

Comment: My first suggestion would be to `Logger.log` everything you can, and email it to try and figure out what's going on at each step. What are you getting as a response from the `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?

Comment: The UrlFetchApp.fetch responds this:
Everything is here at the end of the document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tb0-twzHl-wXbvaNF2IpCT0CiONT9PoqPlEweLz3oYI/edit
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to Google Docs</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, dl,
  dt, dd, ol, ul, li, table, tr, td, form, object, embed,
  article, aside, canvas, command, details, fieldset,
  figcaption, figure, footer, group, header, hgroup, legend,
  mark, menu, meter, nav, output, progress, section, summary,
.. etc..

Comment: It looks like the output what truncated. The log can only take so many characters. To get the full document, try emailing the results of the `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. What you got didn't even get passed Google's CSS. Which might indicated that you are really getting an error page. Have you checked the response code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get response from the published URL it must be published with following settings:

1. **Execute the app as:** me
2. **Who has access to the app:** Anybody even anonymous

It is required because, the way you are fetching the URL, it can access only public available web address.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the headers key into your dictionary that's all
And of course on top of what Hari Das mentioned

**headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}**

```
function merry2script() {
      var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzM97wKyc0en6UrqXnVZuR9KLCf-UZAEpzfzZogbYApD9KChnnM/exec';
      var payload = {payloadToSend : 'string to send'};
      var method = 'post'
      var headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method : method, payload: payload, headers: headers}).getContentText();
      Logger.log(response);
      return;
    }
```